# SQL column value as a Value of a JSON to be inserted into a SQL column

Tags: sql, json

I am migrating some data from multiple SQL columns to a lone SQL column containing a JSON. I will be honest my SQL experience is limited but is this something that could be scriptable or will I have to create some process to do this via a hibernate layer.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Just out of curiosity more than anything, why would you ever want to do this? Isn't the whole point of the database to store your data in a logical relational manner (assuming you're using a RDBMS), then have your application layer construct JSON Objects from the data pulled out of the database?

Comment: agreed, but this is a halfway step till all functionality is moved to Mongo :(

Comment: Depends on your database vendor. Some have internal support for json objects (Like Oracle), others you could create that yourself by using functions or stored procedures.

Comment: Gotcha... All I could think of is to create a stored procedure to build the json string

Comment: @mituw16 : A good reason to use JSON storage (or XML or any object storage) is when you have data which is never used in joins, group by, order by or where statements. If only the application layer is interested in that data, you can keep the structure there instead of in the database in tables with too many vague columns (Very large data storage tends to suffer from this many column issue).

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen Correct me if I am wrong, but at that point, you're basically moving to a NoSQL solution, like mongo as OP suggested. I was more curious why that would ever be a viable solution while using a RDBMS. With NoSQL I totally agree

Comment: @mituw16 : With an RDBMS you can still have the benefits of the RDBMS where you want to. So it is a sort of mixed mode. Nowadays with my data models I tend to go for JSON for structured data complying with my previous comment. Other data I tend to store in key-value structures instead of very wide tables. This prevents many changes to the data model.

Answer (score 0):

without knowing the database ([postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html), etc have native json support),
a great resource for data migration, munging is the python cvskit (which includes a [cvssql](http://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/scripts/csvsql.html) command line tool)

Answer (score 0):

You don't give any details and are very vague.  However, without details it is easy to construct an answer.  For example:

```
INSERT INTO DESTTABLE(COLUMNJSON)
  SELECT "{ val1 : " + field1 + ", val2 : " + field2 + " }" 
  FROM SRCTABLE
```

Comment: You will have to add some UUENCODE to the fields to prevent invalid characters in you JSON.

Comment: naw... The source columns only have whole numbers encoded as a string of digits.  Remember @NorbertvanNobelen I made up this example and the OP gave no details.